# Table - shorten and center \hline

Tags: tables, hhline

I am quite new to using LaTeX and StackExchange. I am trying to shorten and center the \hline in this table. I've circled in red the parts of the line that I don't want. Basically, I want the "Start Point \rightarrow" and "\leftarrow End Point" to  be floating next to the table. If there is an easier way to do this, or a solution has already been posted on a similar question, please let me know. Do tell me if my question is unclear. I appreciate any help you may be able to offer.

```
\begin{tabular}{ cc|ccccc } 

 &  & 0 & A & B & C & $\leftarrow$End Point\\
 \hline{}
 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 5 \\
Start Point$\rightarrow$ & A & 3 & 0 & 2 & 9 \\ 
 & B & 7 & 2 & 0 & 6 \\ 
 & C & 5 & 9 & 6 & 0

\end{tabular}
```

[image: fixme]

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

it is simple. instead `\hline` use `\cline{2-5}`:

```
\begin{tabular}{ cc|ccccc }
 &  & 0 & A & B & C & $\leftarrow$End Point\\
 \cline{2-6\emph{}}
 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 5 \\
Start Point$\rightarrow$ & A & 3 & 0 & 2 & 9 \\
 & B & 7 & 2 & 0 & 6 \\
 & C & 5 & 9 & 6 & 0
\end{tabular}
```

or with use of `\hhline`:

```
\begin{tabular}{ cc|ccccc }
 &  & 0 & A & B & C & $\leftarrow$End Point\\
    \hhline{~-|----~}
 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 7 & 5 \\
Start Point$\rightarrow$ & A & 3 & 0 & 2 & 9 \\
 & B & 7 & 2 & 0 & 6 \\
 & C & 5 & 9 & 6 & 0
\end{tabular}
```

where in document's preamble you need to load package `hhline`.

for more about table setting see [Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) on wikipedia or other introductory text about `latex`